# apt-get hangs on Setting up grub-pc

Tags: apt, grub2, upgrade, dpkg

Yesterday I did my usual

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Everything went fine until it hit

```
Setting up grub-pc (2.02-2ubuntu8.12) ...
```

where it became unresponsive. I ended up killing the process and trying to fix it with

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

but the same thing happens. If I recall correctly from previous upgrades, `grub-pc` brings up a text based GUI on the terminal that lets you select some parameter before continuing the process. I suspect the reason it hangs is because it's waiting for me to select something, but I have no way of doing it because the menu never shows up. Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this? I'm afraid of rebooting my computer now. My computer is running `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I did not find out what was causing the issue, but I did manage to effectively fix the problem. If you're at the stage where `apt` is stuck, I've found the only way to kill the process is to kill the terminal session. This will leave stale lock files that I removed by hand. I'm almost certain there is a smarter way to go about this, but nothing else I tried worked. You can try your luck with `dpkg --configure -a` but in my case I had to terminate that process as well because it hangs the same way `apt` does. Just in case I ran `ps -aux | grep dpkg` and killed every associated process.

In my desperation I risked rebooting the computer, which ended up also hanging on the very last step, which I saw by hitting `esc` on the reboot splash screen. I ended up holding down the power button for a hard reset. Booting up the computer worked fine though, and rerunning `dpkg --configure -a` worked after the reboot, allowing me to finish the configuration for `grub-pc`.

I have since run `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Rebooting the machine after this went smoothly, and everything appears to be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you got a popup to confirm with OK .. Navigate using TAB key until "OK" is highlighted and continue.

If it truly hangs, then

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a --ignore-depends=grub
```

Seems helps bypassing the block.

Answer (score 1):

Just hit the same symptoms - stuck on grub-pc config. There were a small number of dpkg processes which seemed to be stuck. I terminated the software update session on the desktop by dismissing the parent terminal, but did not kill the dpkg processes.

I checked the syslog output, and noticed a USB device seemed to be reporting some sort of communication error every 30s :

```
Nov 29 14:14:09 z800 kernel: [80618.076836] xhci_hcd 0000:28:00.0: WARN Cannot submit Set TR Deq Ptr 
Nov 29 14:14:09 z800 kernel: [80618.076840] xhci_hcd 0000:28:00.0: A Set TR Deq Ptr command is pending. 
Nov 29 14:14:09 z800 kernel: [80618.158336] usb 10-2.3: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
```

This was a mass storage device :

```
usb-storage 10-2.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
```

I recalled from previous grub pain that grub configuration concerns itself with disk devices. One of the several devices plugged in to my system at this point was an SD Card reader which currently had no card inserted.

I removed and reinserted 5 out of 6 of my USB devices ( all except the wireless mouse ), and noted that the stuck dpkg processes were no longer present. I think that the install simply ran to completion at this point. From the dpkg log :

```
2020-11-29 14:08:00 status half-configured grub-pc:amd64 2.04-1ubuntu26.7 
2020-11-29 14:27:58 status installed grub-pc:amd64 2.04-1ubuntu26.7
```

Now, when I ran software update, it reported that the system was up to date.

So my speculative conclusion is that, at least for some such devices, grub-pc configuration can fail to handle empty SD Card readers and gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I unplugged all my unnecessary USB devices and it started right up