# apt-get stuck on "Setting up libc-bin"

Tags: apt, dpkg

Whenever I try to apt-get install a package I get the message:

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

So I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but then I always get stuck for very long on

> Setting up libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...

Full log:

> user@dell:~$ sudo apt-get remove libc-bin
> [sudo] password for user: 
> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
> user@dell:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a 
> Setting up libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...

I already tried several things:

- update and upgrade: `sudo apt-get update`, 'sudo apt-get upgrade', same issue
- Reinstall libc-bin with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin`, but it still only reminds me to run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'
- download libc-bin deb package manually from https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/bionic/libc-bin and install it with `sudo dpkg --force-all -i libc-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb`, same error

Another idea would be to completely delete libc-bin package, but I read that in this case I would not be able to use my bash anymore... ([Can I delete libc-bin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515332/can-i-delete-libc-bin))

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.05 LTS (I considered an upgrade to 20.04 but for this I would need to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` again which raises the same error).

Comment: Looks wierd , can you run any apt commands ? If not then it looks like you need to wait until libc-bin is being settled up ( 1 - 2 hours to be maximum )

Comment: Also other apt commands like 'sudo apt-get install vim' are stuck at Setting up libc-bin.

I will try again waiting for 2 hours, but I waited for at least an hour already.

Comment: Waiting for longer time didn't solve the issue, the process remains stuck on 'Setting up libc-bin'

Comment: Hi Just curious to know that is your problem solved ?

Comment: Hi Algnis, unfortunately I wasn't able to solve it yet..

Comment: [edit] the question and add a "." Which will just make the question active again

Comment: Again curious to know if the problem is solved or not 

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1216429/1460940